# How is this possible (electric field integral)?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, integration, calculus

In the electric field subject, $dq$ is ok to integral. How is this possible? $Q$ is not even changing variable. Can you explain its math?
$$E=k\int \frac{dq}{r^2}.$$

Comment: Can you provide an example or some context of what you mean by this?

Comment: @RaadShaikh added

Comment: The total charge may not be a variable, but you have to add up contributions from all the little bits of charge here and there, and adding up a lot of small things is just integration.

Comment: @RaadShaikh Please consider converting your second comment to an answer. Comments should be used to improve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider from one-dimensional calculus

$$
\int_a^b \mathrm dx = b-a
$$

or its indefinite cousins

$$
\int x^2 \ \mathrm dx = \frac13 x^3
\\
\int x \ \mathrm dx = \frac12 x^2
\\
\int \mathrm dx = x
$$

In your case the “bare” integral might be better written as

$$
q = \int \mathrm dq
= \iiint \rho(\vec x)\ \mathrm dx \mathrm dy \mathrm dz
$$

where $\rho(\vec x)$ is the charge density.
Read $q = \int \mathrm dq$ as “the total charge $q$ is the sum of all the little bits of charge $\mathrm dq$ everywhere.” Beware that if you’re talking about “point charges,” as we often do in electromagnetism, then you have to do some ugly calculus-magic to come up with a sensible definition of the charge density.

The example in your question (v2) is a little *too* condensed to be useful as more than an illustration, because the electric field $\vec E(\vec x)$ is a vector function of the relative positions of all the little bits of charge and the point where you’d like to know the field. The charge integral needs to be weighted by the vector $\frac{\hat r}{r^2}$ rather than the scalar distance-squared $r^{-2}$.  But for the scalar potential, I find

$$
U = k\int \frac{\mathrm dq}{r}
$$

to be a useful shorthand for the messier expression

$$
U(\vec x) = k \iiint \frac{\rho(\vec x’)}{\left|\vec x’-\vec x\right|} \mathrm d^3 x’
$$

The second one is what you need if you’re actually *computing* the integral, but the first makes it much easier to *talk about* the integral.